# How do I use jquery to total fields in rows for a variable number of rows

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add the option fields on a row to the total field on the row, using jquery. I can't use ids because there are a variable number of rows, that get created with clone as the user needs them.

```
<tr>
<td><input name="option_1[]" type="text" class="integer add_to_total"  /></td>
<td><input name="option_2[]" type="text" class="numeric add_to_total"/> </td>
<td><input name="option_3[]" type="text" class="numeric add_to_total"/> </td>
<td><input name="total[]" type="text"   class="numeric is_total"  /> </td>
</tr>
```

I thought of attaching a change event to the input fields with the 'add_to_total' class and using the sibling function to add to the 'is_total' class.  but I can't get that syntax right:

```
$(".add_to_total").change(function() {
    var line_total = 0;
    line_total += $(this + " .add_to_total").siblings().val();
    $(this +  " .is_total").siblings().val(line_total);
});

I get syntax errors and it doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.add_to_total').change(function(){
  var total = 0;
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');
  row.find('.add_to_total').each(function(){
    total += this.value.replace(/[^\d\.-]/,'')*1;
  });
  row.find('.is_total').val( total );
});
```

The `replace()` allows the user to enter `1,000` and not have you end up with `NaN` for your total.

If speed is a big concern, I might suggest caching the `row.find('.add_to_total')` as jQuery data on the row, but that's an optimization best left until you're sure you need it.

Comment: I think it is meant to be done on a per-row basis, so `$(this).closest('tr').find('.add_to_total').each(...`.

Comment: While you're at it, wrap the `$(this)` before the current `.closest()`, and consider using `this.value` instead of `.val()`. :o) EDIT: You cached the row. Even better.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you've suggested, you'll use something like:

```
$(".add_to_total").change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".add_to_total").each(function() {
        total += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $(".is_total").val(total);
});
```

The trick is that even when just one changes you have to recalculate the sum of all of them.

EDIT: On a per-row basis, this might work:

```
$("tr > .add_to_total").parent().each(function() {
    var tr = $(this);
    tr.find(".add_to_total").change(function() {
        var total = 0;
        tr.find(".add_to_total").each(function() {
            total += Number($(this).val());
        });
        tr.find(".is_total").val(total);
    });
});
```

Comment: thank @psmay, except, I think this would not work if there are more than one rows. The total would include the values for all rows